# Show HTML on desktop like conky on linux

Tags: linux, desktop, org-mode

I'm migrating to org-mode and trying to replace desktop calendars (Rainlendar) with org-agenda outputs.

Conky is my first choice, but after all it is not easily written to show such things like the agenda. The syntax has its quirks and there are other issues.

I would like to work with HTML and conky doesn't do that currently. Is there a light-weight desktop app that would show static HTML content with periodical refresh from a file? It doesn't have to support all of the HTML. If the software would react to mouse clicks (to launch the agenda to a larger window, for instance), it'd be preferred.

Comment: Yes, I know org can export to ICS. I tried to migrate that in Rainlendar but resulted in too much hassle.

Answer (score 1):

A bit later, but I just found this [solution](http://www.webupd8.org/2009/04/conky-like-desktop-info-application.html):

> gtk-desktop-info is a python tool to display various pieces of information directly on the desktop, using plugins for html rendering, with html templates and css style sheets for formatting.
>
> The application has been created off the back of existing python scripts used with Conky. The reason for it's creation is a simple one, Conky is great but formatting can suck sometimes and html seemed the obvious choice of formatting giving the user the ability to construct output in a variety of styles based on understood techniques.
>
> General points to note about the app are:
>
> - Very lightweight and low cpu usage
> - Creates cropped images of the background wallpaper and uses them for the generated html background, effectively making the window transparent.
> - Utilises webkit html rendering engine and supports images, javascript and flash as you would expect in the browser
> - Ability to customise any output within the boundaries of what can be done with html, and as it's html there are plenty of editors out there which can help with design
> - All output content is scrollable, so the window size remains unchanged. Using the scroll wheel on a mouse will alway you to see the extra content
> - Variety of plugins available and you also have the ability to use external scripts for rendering content too

Hope it can help.

The package is [Gtk-Desktop-Info](http://fr.scribd.com/doc/14556433/Gtk-Desktop-Infoguide).

Comment: It's good. :) I'm not running Ubuntu so I'll have to look into the details on installing

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what your source org file looks like, but have you tried the "ascii" export option? (C-c C-e a) You could create a [batch agenda export](http://orgmode.org/manual/Exporting-Agenda-Views.html) job that produces a ascii version of your file or subtree and then have Conky pull in the contents of that exported file.

Comment: I export the org-agenda parts in text in a batch process, and I want to apply some coloring to it, hence the question.